# Stored Procedure in cursor firing only once

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, cursor

I am getting an output from a stored procedure but in my cursor it only returns the first value.

SP 1

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[register_system_email_audits]
    @UserId int,
    @EmailFor varchar(500),
    @DateSent datetime,
    @UniqueKey varchar(20) output
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [SystemEmailsAudit]
           ([UserId]
           ,[EmailFor]
           ,[DateSent]
           ,[UniqueKey]
           )
     VALUES
           (@UserId 
           ,@EmailFor
           ,@DateSent
           ,(SELECT CAST( CAST(RAND() * 100000000 AS int) as varchar(20)))
           );
     SELECT @UniqueKey=s.UniqueKey FROM [SystemEmailsAudit] s 
        WHERE s.RecordId=SCOPE_IDENTITY();

END
```

SP2

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [SendNewsletterMails] (@nLID int,
@Category varchar(50))
AS
  DECLARE @html varchar(max),
          @Description varchar(100),
          @Subject varchar(50),
          @Email varchar(100),
          @listID int,
          @DLC smalldatetime,
          @Date datetime = NULL
  SET @html = (SELECT
    html
  FROM NewsLetter
  WHERE nLID = @nLID)
  DECLARE crsEmailList CURSOR FOR
  SELECT
    email,
    ListID
  FROM lists
  WHERE category = @Category
  AND (DLC < DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())
  OR DLC IS NULL)
  OPEN crsEmailList
  FETCH NEXT FROM crsEmailList INTO @email, @ListID
  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
    --Add Beacon
    DECLARE @UniqueKey varchar(20)
    EXEC [register_system_email_audits] @ListID,
                                        @email,
                                        @Date,
                                        @UniqueKey OUTPUT
    SET @html = REPLACE(@html, '[keyvalue]', @UniqueKey)
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_Name = 'Local Server',
                                 @recipients = @email,
                                 @subject = @Subject,
                                 @body = @html,
                                 @body_format = 'HTML'
    FETCH NEXT FROM crsEmailList INTO @email, @ListID
  END
  CLOSE crsEmailList
  DEALLOCATE crsEmailList
GO
```

The stored procedure returns the proper @UniqueKey but only for the first record in the cursor. I have been contemplating a while loop or a temp table but settled on the cursor route for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first time you do this:

```
SET @html = Replace(@html,'[keyvalue]', @UniqueKey)
```

@html will no longer contain [keyvalue].  The next loop iteration that does the same thing will no longer have a [keyvalue] to replace with your uniquekey, so it will still have the old uniquekey.  You may have to set @html back to it's original value that included [keyvalue] somewhere in it.

I'd also recommend changing SP1 to:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[register_system_email_audits]
    @UserId int,
    @EmailFor varchar(500),
    @DateSent datetime,
    @UniqueKey varchar(20) output
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @UniqueKey = CAST( CAST(RAND() * 100000000 AS int) as varchar(20))
    INSERT INTO [SystemEmailsAudit]
           ([UserId]
           ,[EmailFor]
           ,[DateSent]
           ,[UniqueKey]
           )
     VALUES
           (@UserId 
           ,@EmailFor
           ,@DateSent
           ,@UniqueKey
           );

END
```

It will avoid an additional Select statement that is unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you John, I put the set @html = (SELECT html from NewsLetter where nLID=@nLID) into the cursor loop and it worked!